# A question regarding the sentence 俺は悪魔をできるだけ苦しむように殺してやりたいぜ

Tags: grammar

I was reading a book about hunting demons (悪魔) and some other things. I then encountered this sentence, which is in the bold:

> おい。なんで悪魔の力使わなかった?　あ俺の力使ってで悪魔を殺すとよぉ。すっげぇ痛いそうなんだわ。だから俺もコイツみてえな魔人になってかもしれねえからな。それでなんか楽に殺して。やりたくて。いいか覚えとけ。魔人も立派な悪魔だ。デビルハンターが悪魔に同情するな。俺の家族は全員目ので悪魔に殺された。下にいる警察とものみ行ったことあるけどなあ。奥とか子供を守るために命がけで仕事をしてる。お前以外全員本気なんだよ。**俺は悪魔をできるだけ苦しむように殺してやりたいぜ**。お前は悪魔となかよしにでもなりたいのか?

I'm just wondering: Is there a reason why the 悪魔 is marked with を not が? I believe I understand the sentence but I'm just wondering who is doing the 苦しむ-verb which is intransitive. Is it 悪魔?

I appreciate it if someone can explain. If needed, I can give more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, the following sentences are interchangeable:

1. 俺は悪魔**を**できるだけ苦しむように殺してやりたいぜ。
2. 俺は悪魔**が**できるだけ苦しむように殺してやりたいぜ。

They both mean "I want to kill demons so that they suffer as much as possible".

In the former, 悪魔 is the direct object of 殺す, and the sentence is the same as 俺はできるだけ苦しむように悪魔**を**殺してやりたい (still, the implied subject of 苦しむ is 悪魔). In the latter, 悪魔 is part of the ように ("so that") clause, and the direct object of 殺す is implicit.